# Within a ListView - GridViewColumn change content based on ComboBox Selection

Tags: c#, wpf

I am struggling trying to understand how I can allow a user to select a value from a combo box in a GridView column and have that selection impact other items within that GridView column (Labels, Textbox, etc).  If they simply select an item from the combo box I don't appear to have the selected item / index from the ListView nor do I have the GridViewColumn so I can access its contents...This is most likely user error as I am new to WPF.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

So in the xaml below I want to be able (for example) change the Label content for a given combo box selection. I can detect the combo box selection in code behind, but need to be able to access the other elements in that grid view column.

**EDIT:** ListView could be the wrong choice to begin with.  I tried DataGrid as well, but this seemed to allow more flexibility within the columns for dynamic content.

Xaml:

```
<Grid x:Name="GridWindows" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ListView x:Name="LvValues" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource AlternatingListViewItemStyle}" AlternationCount="2">
            <ListBox.Items>
                <sys:String>Value1</sys:String>
                <sys:String>Value2</sys:String>
                <sys:String>Value3</sys:String>
            </ListBox.Items>
            <ListView.View >
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Value" Width="120" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Terminal" Width="50">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                               <CheckBox IsChecked="False"></CheckBox>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Distribution" Width="400" x:Name="Distribution">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                <ComboBox Width="100" x:Name="CbDistribution" SelectedValuePath="Content" SelectionChanged="CbDistribution_OnSelectionChanged">
                                    <ComboBoxItem x:Name="Beta">Beta</ComboBoxItem>
                                    <ComboBoxItem x:Name="Constant">Constant</ComboBoxItem>
                                    <ComboBoxItem x:Name="Gamma">Gamma</ComboBoxItem>
                                </ComboBox>
                                    <Label x:Name="DistributionArg1" Content="k="></Label>
                                    <Label x:Name="DistributionArg2" Content="Theta="></Label>
                                    <Label x:Name="DistributionArg3" Content="Other="></Label>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
```

Comment: Do i understand correctly, that from the user's perspective the combobox is somewhat part of the column header, where he can change/manipulate the appearance of the data in the column? If yes, put your combobox in the header template for the respective column header. I am not really sure what you try to achieve, but if you really want to manipulate the ListView items, you should manipulate your ItemsSource collection directly...

Comment: Thanks elgonzo...they can change the selection in each GridView row.  So the selection in the row would then need to change the items in that row for the given selected combo item.

Comment: Wait, rows or columns? In your question you said **"impact other items within that GridView column"**, but in your last comment you spoke about rows...

Comment: For the GridViewRow the user could select an item from the combo box from that row and I want it to impact the items in a GridView column for that row and that row only.  Does that help? Sorry if I am not being clear.

Comment: I see now. You can probably do this with data binding and a bit of code-behind logic. The key for doing it is to understand the type/structure of the collection the ListView is showing. Could you please expand your question with detailed information about the data type(s) used in the collection you assign to the ListView's ItemsSource? (To avoid other people having a similar confusion like me, perhaps clarify your question as well.)

Comment: Could you create objects (e.g. `ViewModels') that grouped your logically related items (per row), and use a collection of those as your ItemsSource? Changes to properties on these objects could then change the other related properties displayed in the other columns (or set different modes for entry). You'd need to explain a bit more about the data you're storing/binding.